# How can I sort a DataFrame by date ddMMMyyyy?

Tags: python, sorting, datetime

I have a sample dataframe as follows.

**How can I sort it by the index by year instead of by month?**

```
test=DataFrame([1,2,3],index=['28FEB1993','28FEB1994','30MAR1993'],columns=['value'])
```

I would like to have the following dataFrame as the result

```
test=DataFrame([1,2,3],index=['28FEB1993','30MAR1993','28FEB1994'],columns=['value'])
```

I think I stuck at how to parse ddMMMyyyy data format to a datetime object.

Thanks aton!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `strptime`:

```
from datetime import datetime
test.index = np.array([datetime.strptime(s, "%d%b%Y") for s in test.index.values])

test.sort_index()
#           value
# 1993-02-28    1
# 1993-03-30    3
# 1994-02-28    2
```

Or as suggested by @chrisb:

```
test.index = pd.to_datetime(test.index, format="%d%b%Y")
```

Comment: Faster to use `pd.to_datetime(test.index, format="%d%b%Y")`

Comment: @chrisb Thanks. Just getting there!